# Master Data Services - Leaf members Subscription View

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

In MDS, I set up an entity with a simply hierarchy:

```
MasterGroup
-- SubGroup
---- Product
```

There are a few other entities, basically functioning as pick-lists for columns on the Product level. I.e. Sales has their way of looking at products, which they split into 5 categories. Finance does the same, but they only want 3 categories.

The product thus looks like the following:

```
ProductCode (internally generated by MDS)
ProductName 
ProductSubGroupValue
LookupProductID (From source system, which lacks these departmental categorization)
FinanceGroupingValue
MarketingGroupingValue
```

There are about 40 products to be grouped using this hierarchy, with all non-specified products to be dumped into a "catch-all" category.

Everything looks fine, the products have been set up, I can see all the data when I use the Excel MDS plugin, and so I created a view using my Hierarchy to expose the data in SQL Server, and using SSIS I will then source the above columns.

Is this the correct way to set something like this up in MDS, or would you advise me to use a different approach?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do both FinanceGroupingValue and MarketingGroupingValue are in MasterGroup? so 1 SubGroup can belong to more than one MasterGroup?

Comment: @Wendy Both are more like attributes on the Product level. So yes, it's possible for that scenario to happen. Initially we assumed things were structured into proper hierarchies, but got questions when we saw some of the groups ending up under multiple "parents" (which could be fine, but then we'd suggest them to use slightly different names). Turns out there were no actual hierarchies there, but things are just grouped differently depending on who is looking at it.